# Install private dependencies via NPM

Tags: node.js, git, github

According to [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), we can use git repositories as NPM dependencies:

> Git urls can be of the form:
>
> ```
> git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
> git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
> git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
> git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
> git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
> ```
>
> The commit-ish can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to git checkout. The default is `master`.

That's fine and works like a charm, for public repositories. For private repositories (e.g. from GitHub), I tried this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "builder": "git+ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I do `npm` install, I get the following output:

```
$ npm i
npm WARN package.json test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json test@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! git clone ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git Cloning into bare repository '/home/....'...
npm ERR! git clone ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git 
npm ERR! git clone ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone ssh://github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: Cloning into bare repository '/home/...'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

This error appears only for private repositories.

I have the access to this repository and doing `git clone ...` works, via SSH.

What's the solution for this issue?

Comment: @steveax Via SSH. Olli K's answer is correct. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says in the documentation, the git url needs to be in this form:

`git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish`

and I believe github needs to be accessed over ssh with the user `git`, thus your dependency url should probably be:

`"git+ssh://git@github.com/IonicaBizau/myprivatemodule.git"`

Comment: I forgot to add the username!

Answer (score 1):

For me, only changing the url didnt make it work. Here are the steps I had to take to fix this :

- `git+ssh://git@github.com:owner/repo.git#master`
- Create a deploy key and add it to the repo
- Edit git config (`~/.ssh/config` create the file if it doesnt exist) to force the use of the DeployKey instead of the default ssh key

After that the npm install simply worked. All the other options and solutions resulted of the npm install breaking

Answer (score 0):

I had been using the Node.js prompt and a Babun prompt which have been working fine for me.  I got this error with "npm install" on a new repository.  When I used the Git Shell from GitHub it worked fine.

I had already setup my SSH keys and did not have this issue with any other npm installs I did.